# how to make 3 buttons have same margin with end and start container

Tags: next.js, react-bootstrap

I want to create link with button like below

```
| container                                        |
|                                                  |
| [Btn1]               [Btn2]               [Btn3] |
|                                                  |
```

right now, I'm using `justify-content-center`, but it looks like

```
| container                                        |
|                                                  |
| [Btn1]      [Btn2]      [Btn3]                   |
|                                                  |
```

here's the code

```
 <div className={`w-100`}>
     <div className={`d-md-flex justify-content-center`}>
         <Stack className={`${styles.gapHelp}`} direction={'horizontal'} gap={2}>
                        
            <Link href={`/help/faq?key=key1`}><Button variant={'outline-primary'}>btn1</Button></Link>
            <Link  href={`/help/faq?key=key2`}><Button variant={'outline-primary'}>btn2</Button></Link>
            <Link href={`/help/faq?key=key3`}><Button variant={'outline-primary'}>btn3</Button></Link>
          </Stack>
      </div>
    </div>
```

do you know how ?